# Prepending a timestamp to each line of output from a command or executable

Tags: powershell, sqlpackage

I want to prepend a timestamp to each line of output from a command. For example:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

would become:

```
[2011-12-13 12:20:38] foo
[2011-12-13 12:21:32] bar
[2011-12-13 12:22:20] baz
```

where the time being prefixed is the time at which the line was printed. How can I achieve this with PowerShell?

Comment: Not sure why the question was down-voted. You have my +1.

Comment: @avakar I downvoted it; hover over the downvote arrow and the tooltip popup says that downvotes are for questions which show no research effort. Questions which are just statements "I need x" almost always gets a downvote from me, regardless of whether I try to comment or answer helpfully or not, because that's the design of the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your command is a external command named `foo`, you can pipe it's output through a ForEach-Object to add the timestamp:

`foo | ForEach-Object { "$(Get-Date -Format "[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]") $_" }`

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You can make it a named column with something like:

```
x.exe |Select @{Name='XTime';Expression={"[$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')] $_"}}
```

Comment: Should be `HH` instead of `hh`, the latter is for the 12-hour clock system.